# how to Override view folder currently is in vendor

Tags: magento2, product, overrides

I have to override `magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml` file and create it in my theme.

How to override this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override using below folder path in your theme,
**Same as frontend folder templates,**

```
magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Every module from vendor folder in now named `module-*(name of module)`, and in your theme you can translate it to `Magento_*(name of module)`.